# How can I tell that all directories in a SVN working copy point at the same repository root?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

We recently had an issue where TortoiseSVN or AnkhSVN (I can't determine which) crashed in the middle of switching a SVN working copy. Our developer didn't realise that the switch was incomplete, and everything was fine until it came to merging the branch back to trunk, where we learned that some of the changes had already been committed to trunk, and some of the changes had been committed to the branch.

Fortunately, this did not actually affect anything, but I am concerned that this may happen again in the future, and I need a speedy way to test which repository that subdirectories in a working copy point to. Now, in Linux, I could hack a shell script together very quickly to determine this, but I currently don't know how I might find this out in Windows.

I am not entirely against hacking something together using SharpSVN if I have to (and rest assured that I'll share it if I do), but I'd like to know if I can save some time by getting some built in TortoiseSVN or AnkhSVN feature to do it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Powershell use something like below:

```
gci -Recurse | ?{ $_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | %{svn info $_.fullname} | select-string -Pattern "PATH:|URL:"
```

For every folder in your working copy, it will display the path and the url from your repo. If some folder is switched to a branch, you can see that url and the path.

You can easily tweak it to print only the path and urls that are outside of your current branch ( or trunk )

Ignoring unversioned folders is easy:

```
(svn status $_.fullname) -notmatch "\?")
```

So the entire thing would be:

```
gci | ?{ $_.psIsContainer -eq $true -and ((svn status $_.fullname) -notmatch "\?")} | %{svn info $_.fullname} | select-string -Pattern "PATH:|URL:"
```

You need to have a command line svn client like SlikSVN or CollabnetSVN and on path.

Comment: Almost there, I'll edit your post when I've figured out how to compare the directory against the current root, and ignore unversioned directories.

Comment: @Raskolnikov - I have updated to filter out unversioned folders

Comment: Thanks, I got this working with win32svn - http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

Answer (score 1):

If you could make the script in linux you might want to put cygwin on the client so you have access to bash scripting.  Or perhaps perl since they have their own windows install.  UnxUtils is pretty nice as well http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

@manojlds answer is quite reasonable but my tests quickly revealed some problems. First, while it properly filters out non-SVN folders that are immediate children, it does *not* handle grandchildren. The `svn status` command balks on such items with a *"not a working copy"* message. Remember that **Get-ChildItem** does not stop diving down from a folder just because the folder is not a Subversion folder; it notes the fact but keeps digging, so you have to handle the descendants as well.

Next, the `svn info` command balks on ignored items (i.e. on the `svn:ignore` property of a folder) with the complaint *“not a versioned resource”*.

Finally, it can filter out *too much*: it is relying on `svn status` outputting a line beginning with a question mark (indicating unversioned) if and only if the specified folder *is* in fact unversioned. However, because `svn status` on a folder includes *all* of its descendants, if *any* descendant item (file or folder) of a versioned folder is unversioned, `svn status` includes the unversioned status indicator—the question mark—causing the versioned folder to then be incorrectly skipped by the conditional. The top pane in the figure shows that without an unversioned descendant, both children of the root report normal status. After adding the Resources folder as an unversioned descendant (bottom pane), the report from `svn status` now includes the unversioned child.

[image: svn status includes all descendants]

A better solution is available using **Get-EnhancedChildItem**, a cmdlet available from my open-source CleanCode library (from my [API bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html), open up the PowerShell volume for the documentation, or go to the Downloads link to get the code). This enhanced **Get-ChildItem** already knows how to isolate versioned files and how to focus only on folders, so the code you have to write is much simpler (plus it does not suffer from the above drawbacks):

```
Get-EnhancedChildItem -Svn -Recurse -ContainersOnly |
  % {svn info $_.fullname} |
  select-string -Pattern "^(PATH|URL):"
```

The `–ContainersOnly` option enables this filter to isolate folders, just as the earlier code did:

```
filter FilterContainersOnly()
{
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) { $_ }
}
```

The `–Svn` option enables this filter that corrects the deficiencies of the earlier code:

```
filter FilterSvn()
{
    # Check just the current item (depth => empty);
    # force it to report even if up-to-date (verbose => true); and
    # wrap stderr into stdout (2>&1) for the next step.
    $svnStatus = (svn status --verbose --depth empty $_.fullname 2>&1)

    # Item is non-Svn with status of "?" (unversioned) or "I" (ignored).
    # Descendants, which are still traversed, cause "svn status" to fail,
    # and those of course are also non-Svn.
    $svnFilter = ($svnStatus -notmatch "^[?I]|is not a working copy")

    if ($svnFilter) { $_ }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, despite the age of the topic. I don't actually use SVN anymore (as I have been tempted away by the sweet siren call of Mercurial where this sort of issue can't happen), but your response does seem very helpful. Hopefully this will be helpful to other people who are hoping to solve this issue.