# How do I tell if an svn workspace has been 'switched'?

Tags: svn

If I have a workspace that was initially checked out from a repository `~/trunk`, then at the end of the last week I may or may not have run: `svn switch ~/branches/somethingcool .` , but a weekend has passed and I can't remember if I switched myself back, what can I do to check that?

Answer (score 4):

`svn info` will tell you which repository your working copy is linked too.

Comment: Is there a way to have this command look recursively for switch descendant directories?

Comment: You could do something like:  svn info -R | less and then search in less for the directory that you think you might have switched too.  Something like /dir.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned just SVN, I will point you to my answer regarding the same thing - it is a powershell one liner that will look at your working copy and spew out the repo URL for eac directory. You can get the idea a bash script if you are on *nix:

```
gci | ?{ $_.psIsContainer -eq $true -and ((svn status $_.fullname) -notmatch "\?")} | %{svn info $_.fullname} | select-string -Pattern "PATH:|URL:"
```

[How can I tell that all directories in a SVN working copy point at the same repository root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345438/how-can-i-tell-that-all-directories-in-a-svn-working-copy-point-at-the-same-repos/6346111#6346111)